# Let $z(t) = (3x+2y)\cdot exp(2x^2-y^2)$, $x = \cos{3t}$ and $y = \sin3t$. Evaluate $ z'(1)$.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $z(t) = (3x+2y)\cdot exp(2x^2-y^2)$, $x = \cos{3t}$ and $y = \sin3t$. Evaluate $ z'(1)$.

I know that $$\frac{dz}{dt} =\; \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\,\frac{dx}{dt}\;+\,\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\,\frac{dy}{dt}\ $$

I found  these, and then when evaluated at $t = 1$, $x = \cos(3)$ and $y = \sin(3)$, I obtained the answer $-15.64$ to $2$ decimal places. This is wrong, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach: Unless you're required to do the problem using the chain rule, the easiest path is to just plug in the function values for $x$ and $y$.  So,
$$z(t) = (3x+2y)\cdot exp(2x^2-y^2) \implies z(t) = (3\cos{3t}+2\sin{3t})\cdot \exp(2\cos^2{3t}-\sin^2{3t})$$
Now you can find $z'$ the normal Calc 1 way.  (You have a product rule and ~4 chain rules, it looks like)

Comment: Oh I see, I was not sure I could do it that way or that it was easier, Thank You!

Comment: This method is much easier, and I'm getting correct answers now, Thanks anorton!